# Finding convolution of two functions?

Tags: functions, signal-processing

[1. Continuous Functions $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ definitions' link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lltqS.jpg)

[image]

How to evaluate $(x_1∗x_2)(t)$ at $t = −T, 0, +T$ in terms of $T$

[2. Discrete Functions $x_1[n]$ and $x_2[n]$ definitions' link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNADb.jpg)

[image]

Evaluate $(x_1∗x_2)[n]$ at $n = -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$

Comment: Where are your attempts?

Comment: I'm new to convolution operations. Any help regarding how to approach to solve this problem will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I believe you know the definition of convolution of two functions?

Comment: Looks like homework.